# Subset notation between associations in UML class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have two classes `Person` and `Department` with two associations between them

- `works` and
- `manages`,

and between these two associations there is a `{subset}` (`manages` associations are subset of `works` association).

What should I infer about the object diagram?

1. Each `Person` which is a manager has two links to his department (one for `works` and the second for `manages`), or
2. each `Person` which is manager has only **one** link to his department?

By the way, besides `{subset}`, `{nand}`, `{and}` and `{xor}`, is there any other constraint notation which you can put in a class diagram?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @tomiliJons. If you found an answer to your
question, please consider [accepting
it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) (by clicking the
check-mark), and consider up-voting it (by clicking the up arrow).
Accepting an answer indicates to the wider community that you've
found a solution, gives yourself some reputation points, and gives
some reputation points to the person who answered your question.
If you did not find a satisfactory answer to your question, please
leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined two associations the objects will have two links. Simple as that. You might add a note that `works` is redundant in case `manages` has a non-zero multiplicity (since it will have one of `0..1`).

You can place any constraint you like between associations - as long as they make sense.

Superstructures 2.5 states on p.111:

> `<prop-modifier>` indicates a modifier that applies to the Property.
>
> `<prop-modifier> ::= ‘readOnly’ | ‘union’ | ‘subsets’ <property-name> |
>   ‘redefines’ <property-name> | ‘ordered’ | ‘unordered’ | ‘unique’ | ‘nonunique’ | ‘seq’ | ‘sequence’ | ‘id’ | <prop-constraint>`

Comment: thanks, but what is the meaning of the {subset} in that case? is it trying to say that manages link between 2 objects implies also workers link between them? (consider that there is 0..* multiplicities on each association end).

Comment: If an assoc. `A` subsets an assoc. `B` (that has a multiplicity) then it can hold only those which are in `B`. So `manage` must be one of `works`.

Comment: "is it trying to say that manages link between 2 objects implies also workers link between them?" - yes, that's exactly what it is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that a `subsets` constraint can be defined between association ends (reference properies), but not between associations. So, your question should be better stated as follows. Given a class `Person` with the two reference properies `managedDepartment` and `department`, representing corresponding functional associations between `Person` and `Department`, the constraint

```
managedDepartment subsets department
```

implies that for any person object `p`, the set of departments managed by p is a subset of or eqal to the set of departments p works for. This formalizes the business rule that a person can only be the manager of a department at which (s)he works. Symbolically,

```
p.managedDepartment subseteq p.department
```

Alternatively, one could define that the `manages` association specializes the `worksAt` association, which would imply that for any `manages` link there is a corresponding `worksAt` link.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best question I've seen in a while! To answer your two questions directly:

- Yes, by using `Person` `manages {subsets works for}` `Department`, each `Person` who is a manager will have two links to `Department`:  one for `works for` and one for `manages`.
- Another useful constraint you can use on a property in a class diagram is `{redefines}`.

Redefining a property allows you to change a property's name and tighten constraints within the context of its owning class (and within the context of subclasses). For example, you can say the following things:

- In general, `Deck` `contains` 0..52 `Cards`
- A subclass of `Deck` called `Monster Deck` only `contains {redefines contains}` 0..10 `Monster Cards`
- Another subclass of `Deck` called `Player Deck` only `contains {redefines contains}` 0..10 `Player Cards`
- And so on..

This is very handy for expressing requirements and business rules.